# Confirmation with Bootstrap Button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have following Action Link along with confirmation

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure ?')" href="@Url.Action("Delete","Authers" , new { id = item.Auth_Id })"> Delete</a>
```

So I want to bring this as bootstrap button So I tried like following

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure ?');location.href='@Url.Action("Delete","Authers" , new { id = item.Auth_Id })';return false;">Delete/button>
```

But this confirmation not working here

Comment: Why not just add `class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" to you `<a>` element?

Comment: can't I achieve it with button ?

Comment: Yes, but you should use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" id="Delete">Delete</button>` and `$('#delete').click(function() { if(confirm('Are you Sure ?')) { location.href = '@Url.Action(...); } });` but a delete action should not be a GET. It needs to be a POST because your modifying data

Comment: Okay seems your suggestion easier than above :)

Comment: may be this link will helpful to you : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/891309/Custom-Confirmation-Box-using-Bootstrap-Modal-Dial